# mySQL updating row with a procedure using a dynamic column name

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-columns, mysql-variables

I have been trying to write a stored procedure that involves a user entering in the column they wish to store data in and then the data to be stored. So far this works but the column is hard coded.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cnp_data`.`AddBehavior` (IN StudId INT,
                                           IN ColumnData VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    UPDATE `Behavior`
        SET `Lunch` = ColumnData                        
            WHERE `StudentId`=StudId;
END
```

But I want to make it so that `Lunch` column can be dynamically set by the user. So far I am stuck with this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cnp_data`.`AddBehavior` (IN StudId INT,
                                           IN ColumnName VARCHAR(45),
                                           IN ColumnData VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SET @Var1=StudId;
    SET @Var2=ColumnName;
    SET @Var3=ColumnData;
    SET @sqlstm = CONCAT("UPDATE `Behavior`
                            SET `",@Var2,"` = ",@Var3,"
                               WHERE `StudentId`= ",@Var1,";");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstm;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

But this throws an error when I try to enter in the following CALL statement

`CALL AddBehavior(19, "AM Snack", "test");`

Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'test' in 'field list'

I don't understand why it is trying to find @Var3 as a column instead of setting it as the data inside the @Var2 column.

Thank you all for any help or insights!

Comment: Try adding ` characters around  ",@Var3,"

Comment: Thank you so much, This worked. I've been struggling with this for far too long and I cant believe it was a simple quote error. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

This works, Thank you Anthony McGrath.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `cnp_data`.`AddBehavior` (IN StudId INT,
                                           IN ColumnName VARCHAR(45),
                                           IN ColumnChoice VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    SET @Var1=StudId;
    SET @Var2=ColumnName;
    SET @Var3=ColumnChoice;
    SET @Var4=CURRENT_DATE;
    SET @sqlstm = CONCAT("UPDATE `Behavior`
        SET `",@Var2,"` = """,@Var3,"""
            WHERE `StudentId`= ",@Var1," AND CurrentDate=""",@Var4,""";");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlstm;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```